# Swift 5 Applying coordinator pattern results in blank screen

Tags: swift, coordinator-pattern

In my AppDelegate I have this:

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let rootNavController = UINavigationController()
    appCoordinator = AppCoordinator(withRootController: rootNavController)
    appCoordinator.start()

    window?.rootViewController = rootNavController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

return true
}
```

And then in my AppCoordinator, I have this:

```swift
final class AppCoordinator {

  var rootController: UINavigationController
  let initialViewController: UIViewController

  init(withRootController: UINavigationController) {
    self.rootController = withRootController
    initialViewController = InitialViewController()
  }
}

extension AppCoordinator: Coordinator {

    func start() {
        //rootController.show(rootController, sender: self)
        rootController.pushViewController(initialViewController, animated: false)
    }
}
```

But when I run it I only see a black screen. This pattern used to work for me in Swift 3, but I can't figure out what I'm doing incorrectly with Swift 5.

I've deleted Main.storyboard and erased all references to it from info.plist as well.

Comment: What is a Coordinator? The question seems to be about that but you have not exposed it to our view.

Comment: Also are you aware that if you make a new project in Xcode 11 the `window` of the App Delegate does nothing? The important window is now the `window` of the Scene Delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out.

Apple had moved quite a bit of launch logic to SceneDelegate from AppDelegate, so I just moved my code there, and it worked.

Comment: I'm running through the same issue, but moving my logic to SceneDelegate did not solve it. Can you provide some code to work with or if you can remember the way you did it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the order of initialization of properties.

```
let rootNavController = UINavigationController()
appCoordinator = AppCoordinator(withRootController: rootNavController)
appCoordinator.start()
```

At this stage; you have already called the `appCoordinator` start but your `window` doesn't have the reference to `rootViewController`; which is done later on.

```
window?.rootViewController = rootNavController
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

If you shift above these two lines before the `appCoordinator.start()` call, the problem will get resolved.

Comment: Nope, still black screen.

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you try changing `InitialViewController()` background color to may be `red` and see if it is getting added to navigation controller?

Comment: Did you change anything else? Like in info.plist or in any of the default storyboards?

Comment: Even when I instantiate a storyboard, it doesn't show up.

Comment: I haven't change anything in the `info.plist` but just removed the `Main` keyword from  `Main Interface` from the Deployment Info section. You can find this in the `General`section. I also have project which you can refer to https://github.com/coyo8/photopad.